# Word for [cannot be bought]

Tags: single-word-requests

I attempted to find another term for it, but it seems that none of them caught my interest.
By the way, I need it for the title of my poem.

I was gonna entitled it as "Boughtless Dreams" but it seems that such word doesn't even exist.

Comment: *Cannot be bought* as in *an abstract thing (such as love) that cannot be owned, and therefore, not bought*? (Rather than an object that is just *not for sale* or a person that *cannot be bribed*)

Comment: While one suspects that the poster is looking for the words 'priceless' or 'unobtainable,' there is not enough information in the post to make an informed response. Please reformat.

Comment: 'Incorruptible' may match, but as it stands 'priceless' may be what is meant.

Comment: Or if you mean literally can't be bought, unpurchasable?

Answer (score 1):

#### Priceless

> 1. so precious that its value cannot be determined.
>      *"priceless works of art"*
>      synonyms: of incalculable value/worth, of inestimable value/worth, of immeasurable value/worth, invaluable, beyond price, &c.

Source: Oxford Dictionary Online, via Google